# Checking if Mouse Click was not in a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, flash-cs5

I have number of movieClips on stage, with each having it's own Event Listener. Once Click/Touch the event is called each movie clip does something. For example one movieClip makes about 6 other movie clips visible.

What I want to do is, when the user Touch/Click somewhere else on stage, where there is no movieClip I want to know, so I can perform some actions such as make some movieClips invisible.

P.S the reason why I say Touch/Click is I'm developing this app for Android, however to make testing easier I'm currently testing everything in PC with MouseEvent, rather than TouchEvent. Once I get all the features working, I will switch over to TouchEvent and test it in mobile.

Many Thanks,
 Mike

Comment: you can attach event listener to stage object also..

Comment: but wouldn't this also listen for clicks on movieClips? As they are in stage.  Or I have I got it wrong?

Comment: nope.. stage only will listen to event.. that's not how event dispatching works.. from container it ll come only to stage and go back.. will not reach your movieclips..as they are child of stage, and targeting phase will end on stage only, you can through adobe livedocs.. they have explained pretty well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do a check, it's simple and quick and doesn't require adding code to alter propagation.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(e.target == stage)
    {
        trace("click click");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add event listener to the stage. And in the event handlers of your inner movieclips use event.stopPropagation function to prevent bubble event to the container.